# Select Sequence to generate name for Invoice

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

In Accounting -> Invoices

When creating a new invoice and confirming it, the system will generate the next running sequence from Journal's sequence. However, I need to change it so that I have a Many2One field (already created into the model) named `sequence` to store the sequence to be generated for the name when confirm. The question is I don't know where or what method to inherit and customize in order to achieve such process.

I tried tracking it down to `_compute_name` method in `account.move` model but it goes further into `_get_last_sequence` which is more like a method from a general model that I think I should not be tinkering with it. So, I am stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally ended up solving the issue by overwriting `_compute_name` method in `account.move` model.

```
@api.depends('posted_before', 'state', 'journal_id', 'date')
    def _compute_name(self):
        if self.state == 'draft':
            self.name = '/'
        elif self.state == 'posted':
            if self.sequence.code:
                self.name = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code(self.sequence.code)
            else:
                super(AccountMoveInherit, self)._compute_name()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the sequence for invoice from method **_get_starting_sequence** on **account.move**

Comment: I tried that method too. However, it is not executed on confirm and I don't know why, so I think it is still not the right one.

Comment: Did you check that method is not overridden by any other module for the same class

Comment: I checked it. There is no other module overriding the method.

Answer (score 0):

Check the resequence feature. They moved away from the next sequence by code. Now you generate the first invoice. Select it in the list view and under action you find resequence. Here you can set it to something like 2022-00001 and odoo recognizes the scheme. So from then all next invoices are 2022-00002 and so on.